# Javascript - Adding missing values between two sets of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, coordinates, geocoding

I have a concept in my head but not entirely sure on the best way of realising it.

I'm investigating (in JavaScript) ways to fill in missing co-ordinate data values (in lat/lon pairs) between two points.

I have two co-ordinate pairs below:

```
Point A  lat="32.7188350" lon="-16.7611710"

Point B lat="32.711461" lon="-16.911347"
```

I first need to pull out the latitude and longitude of each pair into a separate value.

So...

```
latA="32.718835"
lonA="-16.761171"

latB="32.711461"
lonB="-16.911347"
```

I want to insert additional (missing) values between latA and latB at that precision.  In this example we would create 7373 additional numbers/latitude points

```
32.718835 - 32.711461 = 0.007374
```

I then want to insert the same amount of corresponding longitudinal points (7373) for each latitude point.
The final result will be 7373 additional co-ordinate pairs - thereby filling in the blanks.

Any advice on how to implement this greatly appreciated.

Comment: a for loop would do it

Comment: From where are you planning to get the longitude and latitude?

Comment: @Jaromanda X  - That makes sense for the latitude, but how would I then insert that specific amount of numbers between the two points for the longitude?

Comment: I feel the questions' a bit unclear, or possibly just me since I am not familiar with lat/long related codes and algorithms. Could someone word it better?

Comment: Make for loop and fill array with objects, each item in array will be {lat: val, lon: val}

Comment: @rmn - that's probably my fault - possibly a bit abstract.  Remove the fact that their lat/lon pairs, and think of them simply ad high precision numbers (negative as well as positive).

Comment: @Huskie69 - using "maths" I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I'm assuming you want a list of points in the line between A and B

The following code will run regardless of how the two points are related to each other, i.e. if latA greater or less than latB, and lonA greater or less than lonB in any combination

It may be a little convoluted, the use of "integers" may be a little over the top, but this should give you an idea of how to proceed

```js
var latA=32.718835,
    lonA=-16.761171,
    latB=32.711461,
    lonB=-16.911347,
    lat = Math.floor(latA * 1e6), // use integers
    lon = Math.floor(lonA * 1e6),
    count = Math.floor(Math.abs(latA-latB)*1e6)+1, // count is always positive, and we add 1 so the following is correct
    lonDiff = (lonB-lonA) / count * 1e6, // this can be either positive or negative, we don't care, it's multiplied by 1e6 so we use integers
    latSign = Math.sign(latB - latA), // so we go in the right direction
    arr = [];
    
for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) { // use <= so we have both A and B in the array

    arr.push({
        lat: (lat / 1e6).toFixed(6),
        lon: (lon / 1e6).toFixed(6)
    });
    lat += latSign;
    lon += lonDiff;
    
}
console.log(arr[0], arr.slice(-1)); // just to show that first/last points are correct
```

Using this code, however, the number of points is always determined by the difference in latitude - in this case, for each 1/1000000 degree of latitude, there's about 20/1000000 degree change in longitude - not sure if you want to interpolate the points dependant on the most or least difference in lat vs lon

This code below is generalised - as it is, it will pick the greater difference to loop through - comments in the code shows the two places to change to make it behave exactly as the above code

```js
var latA=32.718835,
    lonA=-16.761171,
    latB=32.711461,
    lonB=-16.911347,
    lat = Math.floor(latA * 1e6), // use integers
    lon = Math.floor(lonA * 1e6),
    countLat = Math.floor(Math.abs(latA-latB)*1e6)+1,
    countLon = Math.floor(Math.abs(lonA-lonB)*1e6)+1,
    count = Math.max(countLat, countLon), // change to Math.min to use least number of points
    lonDiff = (lonB-lonA) / countLat * 1e6,
    latDiff = (latB-latA) / countLon * 1e6,
    latSign = Math.sign(latB - latA),
    lonSign = Math.sign(lonB - lonA),
    arr = [];
    
if (countLat < countLon) { // change to > to use least number of points
    lonDiff = lonSign;
} else {
    latDiff = latSign;
}
    
for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    arr.push({
        lat: (lat / 1e6).toFixed(6),
        lon: (lon / 1e6).toFixed(6)
    });
    lat += latDiff;
    lon += lonDiff;
    
}
console.log(arr.length, arr[0], arr.slice(-1)[0]);
```

Comment: This is great! I'll have a tinker with this and see how I get on, many thanks.

Comment: Just a quick update - I tested this out (using your least number of points method), dumping to screen using document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));  - works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar task like this:

```js
let points = [[32.7188350, -16.7611710],[32.711461, -16.911347]];
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
 result.push([
  Math.round(Math.abs(points[i][0] - points[i+1][0])*1000000)/1000000,
  Math.round(Math.abs(points[i][1] - points[i+1][1])*1000000)/1000000
  ]);
}
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this problem fits in a linear function, to fill the points between A and B we have to apply the function defined by those points A and B. Here an example:

```js
var pointB=["-16.911347","32.711461"];//x,y

var pointA=["-16.7611710","32.7188350"];//x,y


var slope = (pointB[1]-pointA[1])/(pointB[0]-pointA[0]);

var b = pointB[1] - slope*pointB[0];

var steps = Math.ceil((pointA[1] - pointB[1])*1000000);

var points = []//<-- here the points

for(let i= 1; i<=steps; i++){

    let y = +pointB[1]+(i/1000000);

    points.push([(y-b)/slope,y])

}

console.log(points[points.length-1])//<- just the last value
```

This draw a straight line between A and B. We choose `y` to find values of `x`.